# Why $x\in r(b)$ implies that $Mx\subseteq \text{Ann}^{M}(b)$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a unital ring, $a\in R$ and $M$ be a right $R$-module.   Define the  $$r(a)=\{x\in R:ax=0\},$$ the right annihilator of $a$.  If  $x\in r(a)$, show that $$Mx\subseteq \text{Ann}^{M}(a).$$ Where $\text{Ann}^{M}(a)=\{m\in M:ma=0\}$.  (The confusion I get is that the only correct statement is $Ma\subseteq \text{Ann}^{M}(x)$), but below is the proof.

Attempt:  Since $x\in r(a)$ implies that $ax=0$, then $0=a(xR)$ so that   $xR\subseteq r(a)$.  This implies that $Mx\subseteq \text{Ann}^{M}(a)$.

But I am not so sure of the working.

Comment: You're right, the original statement is wrong, as the counterexample below shows. You could write $Ma\subseteq \mathrm{Ann}^M(x)$, if $ax=0$.  Or alternatively, you could replace the assumption that $x\in r(a)$ with $ x\in \ell(a)$, the left annihilator.

Comment: The "attempt" makes no sense. The statement that "this implies $Mx\subseteq \mathrm {Ann}^M(a)$" does not follow from the sentence before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexamples**

1) Take $R=M_2(k)$, where $k$ is any unital commutative ring.

2) Take $M=k\times k$ with usual structure of $M_2(k)$-right module. Put $a=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&0 \end{array}\right)$ and $x=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\ 1&0 \end{array}\right)$. We have $ax=0$, that is, $x\in r(a)$. Moreover

$Mx=(k,0)$ and $(Mx)a\neq(0,0)$. Therefore $(Mx)\not\subset Ann^M(a)$.